# Outline shader with variable width lines

Tags: image-processing, glsl

I'm attempting to make an outline shader in glsl that supports outlines of various widths, but all of the solutions i'm aware of have excessive texture sampling. A standard sobel filter with a 3x3 kernel gives outlines with a width of 2 pixels, and the kernel size can be increased to give thicker outlines, but an outline of 16 pixels with this method requires 225(?) texture samples per fragment.

Are there any fast post-processing outline techniques that allow for thick outlines?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using laplasian and then sobel kernels in the shaders.Those will never give smooth and nicely looking outlines.Then I found the solution based on [signed distance field](http://contourtextures.wikidot.com/).See this thread for more info:
[GLSL Distance Field transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228024/glsl-distance-field-transparency)